# Display p:dialog depending on conditions

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm struggling in not displaying a dialog on some condition.
What I want to do: from an Invoice.xhml page, push a command button (only displayed for admins).After I pushed this button a function checks if an invoice has already been created or not.

For some reason, it never works the way I want. When I check with the debugger my view returns a false but the dialog is displayed

```
<p:commandButton value="Create Invoice" style="background-color:#4EC873; width: 160px; margin-top: 10px;" id="createoffer"
                            actionListener="#{invoiceView.createInvoice}" oncomplete="{ PF('dlg1').show(); }" rendered="#{InvoiceView.buttonIsDisplayed()}" ajax="true" />
<p:dialog rendered="#{invoiceView.popupDisplay()}" closable="true" header="Hello" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" height="80" resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true" >
                            <h:form id="commentdialog">
                            <h:outputText value="Invoice has already been created"/> 
                            <br />
                            </h:form> 
                            </p:dialog>
```

InvoiceView:

```
public boolean popupDisplay() {

    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    invoice = invoiceDB.getInvoice(this.selectedCar.getInvoice());
    if (invoice == null || invoice.getId() == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Your `commandButton` doesn't have an `update` attribute.

Comment: And your code contains bean name inconsistencies. Please read [ask], especially the [mcve]  part and create one.